# How many views/day are required for a site to break even?

Tags: web-hosting, advertising

What is a rough estimate of how many views/day a site needs to break even on hosting and bandwidth using advertising?

You can assume:

- Two Google ads per page.  Low value content (no ambulance chasers here).
- HTML content with fairly low bandwidth usage per page.
- Standard hosting rates.

Comment: What is a standard hosting rate?  You really need to be more explicit with this question.

Answer (score 2):

Well you obviously need more views per day than Twitter & Facebook a year ago (not sure when they broke through the profit barrier)

ALternatively you could easily get to $'00s or $'000s per month on free hosting - e.g. a Blogspot or WP.com blog.

People have TV and Book deals based upon twitter accounts.

You could easily make a 6 figure income using Blogspot to host a sales page and eJunkie for sales and product delivery.

With Adsense you can easily have between $0.10 and $100 CPM (per thousand views) even if you only make $0.10 to $0.20 per click.

My first niche website many moons ago (well 5 years or so) I was making $0.05 to $0.10 per visitor in a gardening niche. So you could break even with paid hosting at 3 visitors per day.

Comment: I wouldn't use Twitter or Facebook as a benchmark, at least not for this question - their outgoings are a lot more than just hosting.

Comment: I know tons of websites that drive tons of traffic and struggle to cover their costs. I just gave high profile examples. 100 visits per day at $1 CPM is barely going to cover hosting costs. That same 100 visitors at $50CPM is a lot more interesting.

Comment: Well, actually you picked two of the most highly-used websites in the world, and said "you obviously need more views per day"

Comment: Well, actually you picked two of the most highly-used websites in the world, and said "you obviously need more views per day than [those websites]". It's obviously possible to break even with less views per day that those two sites get.

Comment: The guy asking the question @c-ross framed the question based on views per day. In my answer I framed it based on the question asked. # page views is only relevant if you are making more money per page view than the cost to serve the pages, develop the site etc. It seem humo(u)r has no place here.

Comment: Flagging for moderator attention... overuse of the word "easily"! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Surely the biggest variable is the value of the adverts you attract, which depends on your content, and the click-through rate, which depends on the number of visitors?

Comment: CTR is a ratio or percentage which applied to the number of visitors and the value of each action might give you some indication of income. It is often better to look upstream - how much money an advertiser makes, or you make as an affiliate from the traffic that clicks an advert, as that ultimately determines long-term income.

Answer (score 1):

You get (basically) no money from adSense if people don't click on your ads, so you also need to estimate the click-thru adsense rate.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on a few things:

- how much does hosting cost?
- how much does bandwidth cost?
- how much was the development cost?
- how much is the maintenance cost?

Too many variables you have no declared to even take a rough stab at it but since you asked:

> [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_%28number%29) views / day seems reasonable

Comment: Seems to be a fairly low number. What's the source?

Comment: I think you missed the joke. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy

Comment: @John Conde - Of course, how could I miss that? Guess I'm too involved in my current project to parse (X)HTML with regex. Still not quite working the way I want...

Answer (score 0):

Without telling us your average revenue (r) per view, how many views per day (v) you receive, and what your expenses (e) are, it's an impossible question to answer. Of course, once you do tell us those things, it's a simple equation: `r*v*d = e` (d = number of days).